# JSON Support on Oracle 12C Work Not Well

Tags: json, oracle, oracle12c

Oracle 12c has supported JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) data that you can get json string value from DB.
example: 
JSON obj(column name： `my_json`) is `{"account": "10000"}`
table : table1
you can get account value by :

```
select t.my_json.account from table1 t;
```

while you can't get it by `select my_json.account from table1` the table alias is necessary when you use this case. 
when i left join this table and use table alias, it also not work
the sql is looks like that `select t1.my_json.account from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.c = t2.c`
could anyone help me to point out where the issue is.
the Oracle JSON docs related link: **https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm#ADXDB6371**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [Oracle JSON expression](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/expressions010.htm#SQLRF57024) here 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

*Well and Not Well* are subective assesments, but the mandatory alias for JSON selection is well [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm#GUID-7249417B-A337-4854-8040-192D5CEFD576):

> The dot-notation syntax is a table alias (mandatory) followed by a dot (.), the name of a JSON column, and one or more pairs of the form . json_key or . json_key followed by array_step, where json_key is a JSON key and array_step is an array step expression as described in Oracle JSON Basic Path Expression Syntax.

Comment: pls see the below comments, i found the JSON expression in Oracle docs, while there is no detail description on JSON expression